# Splashscreen Flicker in iphone 5 Titanium

Tags: ios5

I am developing one application using titanium in iphone, so in that first I am loading a splashscreen so its working fine with iphone 4 but when i tested in iphone 5 the splashscreen flickers and displays as if there is two splash screen loading one after the other.
please help as I am a new bie.

Thanks